# Unable to create new remote session - Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am getting exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true,
>   browserName=firefox, version=48.0.1, platform=ANY}], required
>   capabilities = Capabilities [{}]' while trying to run selenium script
>   in a remote web driver.

Hub and node are configured properly and its able to communicate to each other.

- Selenium web driver : 3.0
- Platform : Windows server 2012 R2.
- Firefox Version: 48.0.1

Code used in my script :

```
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "mypath/geckodriver.exe");
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
     capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
     capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
     capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);

     RemoteWebDriver driver =new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://ipofthenode:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);

     driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com");

     System.out.println("executed");
```

Detailed stack trace:

> an 19, 2017 6:07:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's
>   Law holds true on the remote end Jan 19, 2017 6:07:37 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol. Jan 19, 2017 6:07:37
>   PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection Exception in thread
>   "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to
>   create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities
>   [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=48.0.1,
>   platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}] Build info:
>   version: '3.0.0', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:48:16
>   -0700' System info: host: 'Hostname', ip: 'IP', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_101' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
>     at demo.Grid.main(Grid.java:26)

Comment: Do you have the geckodriver on the remote machine at the correct path? Also share the code you used to start the node on the remote machine.

Comment: Thanks mosaad.It started working after placing geckodriver in node machine.

Answer (score 1):

Create  a .bat file adding below command

```
C:\Selenium_Grid
start java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Selenium_Grid\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe -jar C:\Selenium_Grid\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox -port 5555
```

(replace paths with yours)

then start the .bat file before executing your code